# "There is not enough storage space on the device to store package" when starting Android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, mono

I have just updated Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 (it was a suggested update from Visual Studio).

After the update, when I start debugging with the emulator `AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova (Android 4.4 - API 19)`, the following error occurs:

> The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InsufficientSpaceException: There is not enough storage space on the device to store package: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23.apk. Free up some space or use an SD card and try again.

This did not occur just minutes before the update, and the project remained untouched during the update. I am quite sure about that.

The Xamarin documentation has this error documented [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/), and says:

> > There is not enough storage space on the device to deploy the package
>
> This occurs when you don't start the emulator from within Visual Studio. When starting the emulator outside of Visual Studio, you need to pass the -partition-size 512 options, e.g.
>
> `emulator -partition-size 512 -avd MonoDroid`

But I did start the emulator from within Visual Studio.

Comment: How much internal storage does your emulator have and how much of that is available?

Comment: @CobusKruger I looked it up in the emulator and this is the result: http://i.imgur.com/gRCgahy.png (Available: 77MB, Apps: 162MB, Cached data: 452KB).

Comment: I have removed the current app + another app deployed from a previous debug, and now it works. 1) I didn't realize that previous deployments were stored in the emulator (now I know better), 2) those 2 apps represented only 20MB from the total storage (which seems small to me), 3) the free space when the 2 apps were not uninstalled was 78MB (which seems enough to deploy a 10MB app).

Comment: After the successful deployment, the available storage shown by the emulator is 58MB. After looking it up a bit, I see that I can modify those parameters under `Visual Studio 2015 -> Open Android Emulator Manager (AVD) -> Edit -> Internal Storage`. I am just starting playing with Xamarin and it didn't occur to me that a deployment on an emulator could have these kind of problems. Plus in the end, the solution had nothing to do with what was proposed by the Xamarin doc ("This occurs when you don't start the emulator from within Visual Studio.").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the internal storage size and available storage of your emulator. Default configuration is often not very large.

Comment: I'll post it here again just in case: to change this parameter, go to `Visual Studio 2015 -> Open Android Emulator Manager (AVD) -> Edit -> Internal Storage`. Also, option B is get rid of previous deployments in the emulator (they are saved in the emulator and they take some space. I didn't know about that.).

Comment: @XavierPeña how can one delete previous deployments? I keep getting this error after I deployed my times several times. If I check the device, it shows more than enough place is free, but for some reason I still get this error.

Comment: I find taking down both the emulator and the manager and bringing it back up fixes the issue. If not adb kill-server/start-server does the trick

Comment: I had 4GB on my Android emulator of Android Q (system files) was taking up 3.3GB

Comment: For Visual Studio 2022, this is: from the debug (play) button, you open the dropdown, select `Android Device Manager...`, right click on the desired device, select `Edit`, then increase the `disk.dataPartition.size`.

Answer (score 3):

On MAC if your getting error make sure you increase your **dataPartition** to **1024M**

```
disk.dataPartition.size : 1024M
```

On Mac current config: Feel free to add more bytes if you have a better potato(MacBook pro) than mine

[image: android emulator config on mac]

Answer (score 1):

[Emulator memory issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI9Yv.png)

increase heap size ( make it 2*x).
in my case before it was 256 , then after i made it 512 , now its working fine.

posted by venkat Yanamandala

Answer (score 0):

Cobus answer didn't help for me. Checking the device's storage, I saw that there should be more than enough space left to deploy my app. My only solution so far is to create new device in the emulator every time this happens. It keeps happening after I deployed my app several times (like 50+ deploys).

Comment: The simplest way to get rid of old deployments is to click the little down-pointing menu for your emulator and choosing Wipe Data. That will get rid of everything though, so I guess a better way is to setup the emulator with your account and so on and then duplicate it. Run the duplicate and use the original as your template. It's strange that you get this though - I have 1GB allocated to internal storage and don't run into this at all.

Comment: @CobusKruger Same for me, 1GB storage and it says not even half of it is used. Will update my answer if I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just clean solution and rebuild again it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same issue and managed to resolve it by simply uninstall the previous versions from ADB emulator. To uninstall:
.run the emulator. 
.Drag&Drop the application's icon to the trash.

Answer (score 0):

These following steps work for me

1. Increase Data diskpartition size 1024MB
2. Clean and rebuild again

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by cleaning the android system cache, there are several tools in the playstore for it, im my case i was debbuging with a attached device, so there was nothing to do with the emulator settings.