# Mono.AndroidTools.InsufficientSpaceException: when debugging on device (not emulator)

Tags: android, xamarin

Before updating xamarin studio for VS2015 everything worked fine. Updated Xamarin and suddenly getting this error when deploying to device? Really ticks me off when you update dev tools and get a show stopper like this. Really soaks up precious time. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: are you deploying to a device or the emulator?  Have you verified that you have enough free space available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["There is not enough storage space on the device to store package" when starting Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836021/there-is-not-enough-storage-space-on-the-device-to-store-package-when-starting)

Comment: @Sushi - No that is emulator. As the title of question says this is on actual device.

Comment: @ComeIn Same principle applies, review and free up space on the device's internal storage or depending upon the device's API level, you can flag the install location to be "preferExternal" if you have an SDCard on in the device (Project settings / Build / Android Application / Install Location)

Comment: @Sushi There is ample space on both internal and external storage. I have set android:installLocation="preferExternal" in manifest and set to external in project settings. As mentioned, this was not an issue until I updated xamarin for VS.

Comment: I am able to copy the apk manually and install from device file system. Just fails when deploying from VS.

Comment: Strangely I just cleared the global cache (All Apps) and it deployed again, no problem. The problem seemed to be fixed. However it has come back again and I have done nothing else. This has me stumped!

Comment: @ComeIn How much free space is available on the internal storage partition of that device? FYI: You can also try moving the Mono Shared Runtime to your SDCard (Setting / Apps / Mono Shared Runtime / Move to SDCard) to see if that helps clear up some internal storage...

Comment: @Sushi 115MB free. Are you saying there should be a "Move to SDCard" options when I select : Setting / Manage Apps / Mono Shared Runtime ? If so I don't see that option on my phone.

Comment: @ComeIn That option has been available since froyo(? i think)... http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/articleimage/9274/2010/08/thumb_550_solo-move-sd.png

Comment: @ComeIn With only 115MB free and some of that being fragmented, I understand why you *could* get the out of space exception... I would look at moving other apps to your SD Card to try to free up a larger chuck of flash for `adb` to work with.

Comment: OK, Looks like my Huawei does not have that option. May have to shout myself a better device :). Thanks for your help Sushi.