# Xamarin Emulator - Remove Previous Deployments

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation

I'm developing a medium sized Xamarin application, with intensive data processing. I can do about 10 deployments before the internal disk space is to full. I did some searching and came across this one question - same issue but I'm looking for an actual solution.

["There is not enough storage space on the device to store package" when starting Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836021/there-is-not-enough-storage-space-on-the-device-to-store-package-when-starting)

It's not feasible for me to wipe the device when this error occurs due to the nature of the application. Is there away to wipe out the previous deployments but retain the application data and not uninstall the application or wipe the emulator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start the emulator via the cmd-line and use the `-partition-size` (in MB) to increase the size of the "internal storage" (the default size that Xamarin starts it with is 512mb). This will be reflected with the Storage section of Setting on the emulator.

i.e.

```
emulator.exe -avd Pixel_XL_API_26_PlayStore.avd -partition-size 4096
```

Note: To avoid the partition being reset, do not change to a value less than what you were using, increasing the size is always safe(?)....

re: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do have it set at 4GIGS already. What I'm trying to solve is the build up of each build, as outlined in the above scenario. Due to the nature of the application this is not feasible. Thanks!

Comment: @jazzmasterkc If the "internal disk space" is full, increase the partition size, otherwise output your app's data to the external SDcard and attach a larger sdcard to the emulator using a custom sized file (`-sdcard`).