# Xamarin - System image download error when creating emulator device

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to use the xamarin emulator and while creating I get the error of not having enough disk space on the disk as show on this image. [image: errorImage]

Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37837294/34092

Comment: already tried those solutions but it seems that their error happens not every time. I can't even create the emulator for the first time.

Comment: You could try to reinstall the Android SDK. And check the space on your PC and run the emulator with VS.